# Detect which column has the greatest value

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
id | a | b | c | status
---+---+---+---+--------
1  | 3 |12 |6  |   b
2  | 5 |8  |56 |   c
3  | 99|7  |23 |   a
```

I would like to detect which column has the greatest value (1,2 or 3) and then record the "status" of that row highest value (I used a,b,c just for the example)

How could I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: in your subject you say "which row" but in question's body you say "which column"!!!! which one is right?!

Comment: What should happen if there is a tie?

Comment: I only understood the question after reading the answer...

Comment: Sorry, i meant "column". In case of a tie it shouldn't update the status...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE GREATEST(a,b,c)
        WHEN a THEN 'a'
        WHEN b THEN 'b'
        WHEN c THEN 'c'
    END AS status
FROM yourtable
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d1aa/1)

Rewritten as an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET status =
    CASE GREATEST(a,b,c)
        WHEN a THEN 'a'
        WHEN b THEN 'b'
        WHEN c THEN 'c'
    END
```

Comment: Great answer. He wants to store status as the "status" column, so you'd need an update: `UPDATE abc SET status=
    CASE GREATEST(a,b,c)
        WHEN a THEN 'a'
        WHEN b THEN 'b'
        WHEN c THEN 'c'
    END`

Comment: @MarkByers I need to put this query along with other SET and with a WHERE clause. Something like... `UPDATE yourtable SET something = '1' SET status = CASE GREATEST(a,b,c) WHEN a THEN 'a' WHEN b THEN 'b' WHEN c THEN 'c' WHERE id = 2 END` Can you help me on how to do this query? Thanks!!

Comment: @Santiago: Use comma (`,`) instead of second SET, and `WHERE` must come after END. I suggest you read a beginner book about MySQL - it will teach you these basic rules.